# unable to launch startxfce4 x session --- "startxfce4" not found

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, xubuntu

recently i have tried to upgraded ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 and it got crashed. somehow i upgraded it to 14.04 and now i can able to see login screen.

my problem is when i tried to login i am getting error say `unable to launch startxfce4 x session --- "startxfce4" not found`.

i can able to login through command line but not in GUI.

i have tried `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` but didn't help.

can anyone help me to solve this please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get install xfce4-session` say?

Comment: @muru shall i install it?

Comment: Yes, that package contains the `startxfce4` command according to the [Ubuntu Packages index](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=startxfce4&searchon=contents).

Comment: @muru i have installed it. now i am not getting that error after login but nothing is happening after login.

Comment: Just a black screen?

Comment: yes for both (guest and another account also)

Comment: Uh, is this a dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/512821/no-gui-after-upgrading-from-12-04-to-14-04-1?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop
```